# Import video to iOS Gallery using bash script

Tags: ios, bash, video, import, video-gallery

I am writing a bash video downloader script for iOS, and I would like to know how can I save the downloaded videos to the Gallery. 
So far I got to this point:

```
mv $title.$ext /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_$(printf '%04d\n' $((10#$(ls /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE | tail -n 1 | sed 's/.*_//' | cut -f 1 -d'.') + 1))).$ext
```

To move the video into the Gallery and

```
rm /var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite-shm /var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Photos.sqlite-wal
```

To refresh the gallery, but this last command does not work. I know I can remove the whole PhotoData directory but then a reboot is needed and a long wait for the gallery to reload all the photos and videos.
Is there another way I can do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how does it not work?

Comment: The gallery isn't refreshed even after a reboot.